# Build error when using cloudbuild.yaml with docker and next.js

Tags: docker, next.js, gcloud

I have a project on next.js it uses this Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:current-alpine AS base
WORKDIR /base
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .

FROM base AS build
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /build
COPY --from=base /base ./
RUN npm run build

FROM node:current-alpine AS production
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /app
COPY /next.config.js ./
COPY --from=build /build/package*.json ./
COPY --from=build /build/.next ./.next
COPY --from=build /build/public ./public
RUN npm install next

EXPOSE 3000
CMD npm run start
```

and is deployed into the Google Cloud Run. When using build with this Dockerfile everything is fine. Now I want to have more control over my `.env` so I've added `cloubduild.yaml` like this:

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args:
      [
        'build',
        '-t',
        'gcr.io/cronvall-de-fe/image-id',
        '--build-arg=ENV=$_NEXT_PUBLIC_TEST_VARIABLE',
        '.',
      ]
  # push the container image to Container Registry
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['push', 'gcr.io/project-id/image-id']
images:
  - 'gcr.io/project-id/image-id'
timeout: 1200s
substitutions:
  _NEXT_PUBLIC_TEST_VARIABLE: test
```

and trying to build it with `gcloud builds submit` command. And now I keep getting
`Error: > Couldn't find any` pages`or`app `directory. Please create one under the project root`.

I think the problem is in `cloubduild` file, but I can't figure out where.